# LogicException You must call one of in() or append() methods before iterating over a Finder. after upgrade of laravel 8 to 9 and laravel orchid to 13

Tags: laravel

[image]

> LogicException
>
> You must call one of in() or append() methods before iterating over a
> Finder.

after upgrade of laravel 8 to 9

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73474286/laravel-orchid-you-must-call-one-of-in-or-append-methods-before-iterating

Comment: Did you updated your composer?

Comment: Also according to [this](https://github.com/orchidsoftware/platform/issues/2128#issuecomment-1037253752) *Issue solved by republishing vendor files..*